# Chop off trailing newline for Swift's NSAttributedString

Tags: strings, swift

I've made this extension but I'm touchy around `NSAttributedString`s, keenly aware that Swift refuses to use the traditional notion of integer lengths on Unicode `String`s, what with their graphemes that can compose and overlap. Also, it feels odd to convert to `String` to check for the newline. I'm not worried about `\r` because `\n` is the standard conversion when coming from HTML `<p>` tags. Also is this too long for something so simple? It feels like I'm missing someething

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    var trailingNewlineChopped: NSAttributedString {
        get {
            guard self.length > 0 else {
                return self
            }
            let lastCharRange = NSMakeRange(self.length - 1, 1)
            let lastChar = self.attributedSubstringFromRange(lastCharRange).string
            guard lastChar == "\n" else {
                return self
            }
            let mutableCopy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
            mutableCopy.deleteCharactersInRange(lastCharRange)
            return mutableCopy
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method works correctly, as far as I can see.

For a read-only computed property, you don't need to enclose the
getter method in `get {  }`:

```
var trailingNewlineChopped: NSAttributedString {
    guard self.length > 0 else {
        return self
    }
    let lastCharRange = NSMakeRange(self.length - 1, 1)
    let lastChar = self.attributedSubstringFromRange(lastCharRange).string
    guard lastChar == "\n" else {
        return self
    }
    let mutableCopy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
    mutableCopy.deleteCharactersInRange(lastCharRange)
    return mutableCopy
}
```

Checking for a trailing newline character can be done with
the `hasSuffix()` method on the underlying `string`.

Instead of creating a mutable copy and removing the last character,
you can extract the first `length-1` characters instead.

The method then becomes

```
var trailingNewlineChopped: NSAttributedString {
    if self.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
        return self.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, self.length - 1))
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
```

You can even omit the implicit `self.`, but that is a matter of personal
preference:

```
var trailingNewlineChopped: NSAttributedString {
    if string.hasSuffix("\n") {
        return self.attributedSubstringFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, length - 1))
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
```

`NSMakeRange` will not be available in Swift 3 anymore, so it could
be a good idea to start replacing that by
`NSRange(location:, length:)` in your code.

---

**Update:** Swift 3 changed how Objective-C methods are imported
into Swift:

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    var trailingNewlineChopped: NSAttributedString {
        if string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            return self.attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: length - 1))
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```